# Change $! in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to return a error text from sub in $!. But simple

```
 $! = "Error: Something is wrong!";
```

doesn't work, it doesn't change $!. How can I do it?

Comment: `$!` contains what went wrong...

Comment: Ok    

     $!="This is wrong";

Comment: You should consider "$!" to be read-only.  It's the moral equivalent of perror: http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror

Comment: @Brian Roach, The answers to that question may have useful, applicable advice, but the question is very different, and the answers to that question don't answer this question. It's not even close to being a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

First, [Errno::AnyString](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Errno%3a%3aAnyString).

Second, don't do it.  `$!` is special, and should denote *errno*.  Use `$YourModule::Error` (or whatever) if you need to communicate special errors.

Answer (score 5):

`$!` is reflection of the C library var `errno` (a number) and the error message it represents (as obtained using `strerror` or similar).

You can't change the string because that's a generated value, but you can change the number.

```
$ perl -E'say $!=$_ for 1..10'
Operation not permitted
No such file or directory
No such process
Interrupted system call
Input/output error
No such device or address
Argument list too long
Exec format error
Bad file descriptor
No child processes
```

Your code isn't trying to set `errno`, so it should be using its own variable instead of messing with `$!` (or throw an exception using `die`).